# How to get table name from Django filter objects

Tags: django, django-models, django-1.6

I have diffrent tables with same columns
Like

```
class teachers(models.Model):
    x= models..CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True);
    y= models..CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True);

class students(models.Model):
    x= models..CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True);
    z= models..CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True);
```

I am using a function to process column x of both tables. So If any undesired values come in the value for x, I need to log that with the column name.

Like 
    f = students.objects.filter()

```
def validate_x(obj):
    if obj.x == None:
        logger.error("None object found in table" + str(obj__tablename))
        return False
    else:
        return True

for i in f:
    validate_result = validate_x(i)
```

My actual scenario is not null check. I just tried to explain it with this example.
Is there any way to achieve this. I am using Django 1.6

Comment: are you receiving any error?

Comment: I am looking for the proper syntax for getting table name info. If I give like above obj__talblename, it gives error  NameError: name 'obj__talblename' is not defined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`object.__class__.__name__` or `object._meta.object_name` should give you the name of the model. (if you need model name).

when you need name of db table then you should use `object._meta.db_table`, as arpit-solanki said.

Answer (score 2):

Use this for getting database table name

`obj._meta.db_table`

[This](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/meta/) might be useful but in 1.11